# Replace Excel vlookup with a dynamic formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

I have created a schedule where I am trying to lookup the value of rent for a period of time based on a given date (located in cell `B1`).

For example, I have the following data set:

[image]

- **Rent Change Date** is the date when the rent increases for a specified tenant
- **Amount** is the amount it increases to on the specified **Rent Change Date**
- The schedule off to the right is the monthly rent schedule as dictated by the **Rent Change Date**

I am currently using a `VLOOKUP` to identify the range for each tenant using `TRUE` (or approximate match) to find the rent for the current month (as dictated by the date in `B1`).

Sample (located in cell `G5`): 

`=VLOOKUP(G4, C5:D10, 2, TRUE)`.

For each tenant, I then reset the `table_array` range. This works well for a small data set, but I have been searching for a way to set the range automatically. Is there an efficient way to get all of the **Rent Change Dates** by tenant? Maybe an Excel array formula?

Comment: In what cell do you have your `VLOOKUP` formula? I'm not sure I fully follow how you have this set up.

Comment: For tenant 1, for the date of 1/1/2018, I have the formula vlookup(F4, B5:C10, 2, True).  The formula looks at all of the rent change dates for Tenant 1 and returns the amount that corresponds to the date equal to or after 1/1/2018.  I hope that helps.

Comment: What cell is that formula in? As in, the cell address. When I use your formula, I get an error because the value in `F4` (**Tenant 1**) isn't found in the range `B5:B10` (since `VLOOKUP` only looks in the first column of the supplied range).

Comment: I am confused what you are asking. You can use Index and Match to find the intersect of month and tenant to retrieve rent amounts from the table in the image.

Comment: Hi TotsieMae, the vlookup formula in cell G5 is vlookup(G4, C5:D10, 2, TRUE).

Comment: Hi QHarr, the index and match works well if the date exists and matches exactly but when it doesn't match, I get errors.  For example, if a tenant pays $100 a month starting 1/1/2018 and then on 6/1/2018 pays $150 a month, for the dates of 1/1/2018 to 5/1/2018 I would return $100 and for 6/1/2018 to 12/1/2018 I would return $150.  I don't think the match function works with dates where there are no exact matches.

Comment: I think a *lot* of the confusion is coming from how you have your data structured. I think I finally understand what you've presented (maybe because I work in commercial real estate for a living, but maybe not), so let me look at this again.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm still not 100% sure I understand what you're looking for, but here is what I came up with.

Using this formula in cell `G5` (committing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as it's an **array** formula), and then copying the formula to all other cells in the `G5:R7` range, you *should* get what you're looking for.

#### Array Formula:

```
=IF(AND(G$4>=MIN(IF((--($A$5:$A$19=$F5))=0,2,1)*($C$5:$C$19)),G$4<=EOMONTH(MAX(($A$5:$A$19=$F5)*($C$5:$C$19)),11)),INDEX($D$5:$D$19,MATCH($F5&G$4,$A$5:$A$19&$C$5:$C$19,1),1),0)
```

---

#### Example Results:

**Result when a tenant is commencing during the year**
[image: Result when a tenant is commencing during the year]

**Result when a tenant is occupied for the whole year**
[image: Result when a tenant is occupied for the whole year]

**Result when a tenant is expiring during the year**
[image: Result when a tenant is expiring during the year]

---

#### Explanation:

There's a *lot* going on with this formula, and it's possible there's a simpler way, but I'll do my best to explain. After all, learning isn't just about getting an answer, but also an explanation.

Essentially what you're looking at is a large logical `IF` function (with three arguments: `logical_test`, `[value_if_true]`, `[value_if_false]`). To understand its arguments better, let's break them down:

- **logical_test**

  ```
  AND(G$4>=MIN(IF((--($A$5:$A$19=$F5))=0,2,1)*($C$5:$C$19)),G$4<=EOMONTH(MAX(($A$5:$A$19=$F5)*($C$5:$C$19)),11))
  ```

  - I started with the `AND` function because I am attempting to find if a given date (`G$4`) is either the same as or greater than the *first* **Rent Change Date** for a **Tenant** (this is found using the `MIN` function) ***and*** if the same given date (`G$4`) is either the same as or less than the end of the month (`EOMONTH` function) 11 months in the future from the *last* **Rent Change Date** for a **Tenant**.

    The embedded `IF` function within the `MIN` function is simply there to ensure the correct minimum date is returned. Removing this logical causes the minimum to return 0, which is incorrect for our needs.

    I used the `EOMONTH` function due to the assumption that when the rent changes - including the final rent change - it lasts for a year. Failing to add this piece to the formula would end the rent the same month as the **Rent Change Date**.
  - If both statements within the `AND` function return `TRUE`, the **logical_test** then proceeds to the **[value_if_true]** argument.
- **[value_if_true]**

  ```
  INDEX($D$5:$D$19,MATCH($F5&G$4,$A$5:$A$19&$C$5:$C$19,1),1)
  ```

  - `INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])`
  - `MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])`
  - **COMBINED:** 

    `INDEX(array, MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]), [column_num])`
  - Using the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions together is allowing us to look at the data from any angle without having constraints placed on us. In this case, our **array** argument - `$D$5:$D$19` - spans the entire area of our **Amount** column. *This is where we want to return our value from, so it's important that we cover the full area.*
  - In the place of **row_num** we use the `MATCH` function. In our table spanning `F4:S8` (which includes the column and row names) we are given both the tenant name (`$F5`) as well as a reference date (`G$4`). Combining these with an ampersand (&), we now have a concatenated **lookup_value** for `MATCH`. By concatenating these two together, we are increasing the likelihood that our **lookup_value** is unique and will return us the required information.

    If two tenants happen to have the *same* **Rent Change Date**s but *different* names ***OR*** if two tenants happen to have the *same* name but *different* **Rent Change Date**s, we will get a unique match; in the rare instance that two tenants share the same name ***and*** **Rent Change Date**s, one tenant will need to have something different to stand out, such as a unit number in the name
  - Now that we have our **lookup_value** for `MATCH`, we need to supply a **lookup_array**. Given that our **lookup_value** is a combination of the tenant name (`$F5`) and a reference date (`G$4`), we set our **lookup_array** for `MATCH` to be a concatenation of `$A$5:$A$19` (spans the entire area of our **Tenant** column) and `$C$5:$C$19` (spans the entire area of our **Rent Change Date** column), joined together with an ampersand (&).

    The last argument our `MATCH` function needs is the **[match_type]**. For this formula I chose `1 - Less than` (*Finds the largest value that is less than or equal to **lookup_value**. The values in the **lookup_array** argument must be placed in ascending order*) due to the fact that we are looking for a date that is either the date itself or one that is less than it as well as the fact that our dates are in ascending order for each **Tenant**. If we instead looked for an exact match (**[match_type]** set to `0 - Exact match`), we would receive a lot of errors since the **Rent Change Date**s increase annually, not monthly (like our reference dates in `G4:R4`). Similarly, looking for a greater than match (**[match_type]** set to `-1 - Greater than`) also returns a lot of errors, primarily because the dates aren't in the required descending order.
  - Closing out of the `MATCH` function with a `)`, we return to the **[column_num]** of the `INDEX` function from earlier. While this argument is optional with a one-column array, I entered a `1` for clarity. All this means is that once the `MATCH` function determines which row to grab, I want to get the intersection of **[row_num]** (*which is* `1` *in the case of* `G5` *using the presented formula along with* `2/1/2018` *as the date in* `B1`) and **[column_num]** (`1`) from the **array** (the **Amount** column, `$D$5:$D$19`). `Row 1`, `Column 1` from the **array** is `$150.00`, which is exactly the expected result.
  - The last piece of our formula is to finish off the `IF` statement we started with, entering a value for the **[value_if_false]** argument.
- **[value_if_false]**

  ```
  0
  ```

  - In the case of this `IF` function, we simply entered `0` for the **[value_if_false]** argument. I chose `0` because if the tenant hasn't yet commenced or has expired, we want to reflect a total rent of `$0.00` for a given month.

**Hopefully this all makes sense and is what you're looking for.**

Comment: I am trying to understand your explanations. BUT when I try to use the formula I geta a #Value! Error. Also, when I do, for Tenant2, on date 1/1/2018, I get false, when I think it should be true. Does the formula work for you?  I don't see why I cant replicate your results

Comment: @Oniropolo, this question is over 7 months old. The formula did work for me, yes, but perhaps your situation is different from that of the OP. Did you try committing your answer with CTRL + Shift + Enter?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pivot table based on your data table it can automatically put all the dates across the top row (and you can group by quarter, months, years, days if you so desire).

If you want to search for months, but only have rent rates for years in your source data you may need to use sumproduct. (A pivot table will only include dates where they exist in the source data that I'm aware of, it won't add all dates covered by a range unless explicitly included in that range)

It would like something like below;

```
=Sumproduct($c$5:$c$300,--($a$5:$a$300=$a2),--($b5:$b$300>b$1),--($b5:$b$300<c$1))
```

Assumption here is the grid showing data across the top starts from cell a1, and the source data starts from a5.

Because sumproduct effectively is an array formula (you don't need to use Ctrl + shift + enter, it just behaves the same way as an array formula) it's generally not recommended to apply it to a full column for performance reasons.